# How to show text in newly added admin page

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml

By using [this](http://alanstorm.com/magento_admin_hello_world_revisited) article, I have created one page in magento admin.
But I do not know how to show text in that page.
Here is **AdminhelloController.php**

```
<?php
class Pulsestorm_Adminhello_AdminhelloController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        echo "Hello";
        $this->loadLayout();

        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

But that "Hello" is printed above Magento Admin Panel Menu.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Admin section,you does not write code for content area.

At [Alan strom blog](http://alanstorm.com/magento_admin_hello_world_revisited),`content area` ***`(<reference name="content">)`*** layout  files and block class  does not define for that page.That reason  only `show footer & header of admin section`.

For this case,you  need to define  content area layout  and it respective block class at config.xml file:

```
 <adminhtml>
     <layout>
        <updates>
            <pulsestormadmin>
            <file>pulsestormadmin.xml</file>
            </pulsestormadmin >
        </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml>
```

And **pulsestormadmin.xml** located at ***app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout***

and code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>
    <adminhtml_adminhello_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="admin/template" name="demo" as="demo" template="pulsestormadmin/demo.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_adminhello_index>
</layout>
```

also template  file *demo.html* located at as per layout define ***app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/pulsestormadmin***

and now ... write some code at demo.html,and you can see

Comment: I have not created pulsestormadmin.xml file but, I have written that code in local.xml.Is that fine?

Comment: will works.. sss

Comment: Yes it is working. Thank you once again Amit.

Answer (score 0):

Using 
`Zend_Debug::dump($this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles());`

in controller method, I found the handle. Then in local.xml, I used that handle and then added one new block inside content block.